# h264 inside AVI, MP4 and "Raw" h264 streams. Different format of NAL units (or ffmpeg bug)

Tags: c, video, ffmpeg, h.264, specifications

**TL;DR:** I want to read raw h264 streams from AVI/MP4 files, even broken/incomplete.

Almost every document about h264 tells me that it consists of NAL packets. Okay. Almost everywhere told to me that the packet should start with a signature like `00 00 01` or `00 00 00 01`. For example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/18638298/8167678, https://stackoverflow.com/a/17625537/8167678

> The format of H.264 is that it’s made up of NAL Units, each starting
>   with a start prefix of three bytes with the values 0x00, 0x00, 0x01
>   and each unit has a different type depending on the value of the 4th
>   byte right after these 3 starting bytes. One NAL Unit IS NOT one frame
>   in the video, each frame is made up of a number of NAL Units.

Okay.

I downloaded random_youtube_video.mp4 and strip out one frame from it:

`ffmpeg -ss 10 -i random_youtube_video.mp4 -frames 1 -c copy pic.avi`

And got:
[image: hexdump of AVI]
Red part - this is part of AVI container,  other - actual data.
As you can see, here I have `00 00 24 A9` instead of `00 00 00 01`

**This AVI file plays perfectly**

I do same for mp4 container:
[image: hexdump of mp4]

As you can see, here exact same bytes.
**This MP4 file plays perfectly**

I try to strip out raw data:
`ffmpeg -i pic.avi -c copy pic.h264`
[image: Raw data]

This file can't play in VLC or even ffmpeg, which produced this file, can't parse it:
[image: ffmpeg error]

I downloaded mp4 stream analyzer and got:
[image: Analysis]

`MP4Box` tells me:

```
 Cannot find H264 start code
 Error importing pic.h264: BitStream Not Compliant
```

It very hard to learn internals of h264, when nothing works.

**So, I have questions**:

1. What actual data inside mp4?
2. What I must read to decode that data (I mean different annex-es)
3. How to read stream and get decoded image (even with ffmpeg) from this "broken" raw stream?

**UPDATE:**

It seems bug in ffmpeg:

When I do double conversion:

```
         ffmpeg -ss 10 -i random_youtube_video.mp4 -frames 1 -c copy pic.mp4
         ffmpeg pic.mp4 -c copy pic.h264
```

[image]

But when I convert file directly:

`ffmpeg -ss 10 -i random_youtube_video.mp4 -frames 1 -c copy pic.h264`
[image: with NALs]

I have NALs signatures and one extra NAL unit. Other bytes are same (selected).

This is bug?

**UPDATE**

Not, this is not bug, U must use option -bsf h264_mp4toannexb to save stream as "Annex B" format (with prefixes)

Comment: Annex B bitstream will have start codes. AVCC format in MP4 won't.

Comment: @Mulvya, which document defines format for AVCC?

Comment: See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24890903/5726027

Comment: Okay, I parsed every NAL, replaced size with signature `00 00 00 01`, added header and got after repack: https://my.mixtape.moe/hcmpmi.mp4 - any ideas what wrong?

Comment: @bukkojot did you upload correct MP4? There are size bytes in front of your NALs instead of expected `00 00 00 01` start codes. Look after **mdat** bytes `6D 64 61 74` that is followed by size (not start code) of `00 00 02 A0` meaning 672. Sure enough after skipping 672 bytes (of **SEI** data for decoders), there is another size other `00 00 00 34` followed by 52 **keyframe** bytes `65 88 84 00 2B FF...etc`. You haven't added start codes to the H.264 data in this MP4.

Comment: @bukkojot about your update... does that now add SPS and PPS for decoder setup? I saw your `pic.h264` began with keyframe byte `65` (after size or start code bytes). I'm here today cos still wondering how your MPEG decoder knows the picture size or framerate without any bytes provided for **P**icture **P**arameter **S**ettings (PPS). Using `-bsf h264_mp4toannexb` would fix it amongst other possible options.

Comment: Nothing matters. I just finished my project: https://github.com/bookkojot/mp4fixer

Comment: @Mulvya, VC.One, very thanks to you. I mentioned your names in page of my project.

Comment: @VC.One uploaded file was recoded. It was bug in my inplementation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> *"I want to read raw h264 streams from AVI files, even broken/incomplete."*
>
> *"Almost everywhere told to me that the packet should start with a signature like : 
>  `00 00 01` or `00 00 00 01`"*
>
> *"...As you can see, here I have `00 00 24 A9` instead of `00 00 00 01`"*

Your H264 is in AVCC format which means it uses data **sizes** (instead of data **start codes**). It is only Annex-B that will have your mentioned signature as start code.

You seek frames, not by looking for start codes, but instead you just do skipping by frame sizes to reach the final correct offset of a (requested) frame...

AVI processing :

- Read size (four) bytes (32-bit integer, **Little Endian**).
- Extract the next following bytes up to size amount.
- This is your H.264 frame (in AVCC format), decode the bytes to view image.
- To convert into Annex-B, try replacing first 4 bytes of H.264 **frame bytes** with `00 00 00 01`.

Consider your shown AVI bytes (see [**first**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJGeK.png) picture) :

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00     ................
00 00 00 00 4C 49 53 54 BA 24 00 00 6D 6F 76 69     ....LISTº$..movi
30 30 64 63 AD 24 00 00 00 00 24 A9 65 88 84 27     00dc.$....$©eˆ„'
C7 11 FE B3 C7 83 08 00 08 2A 7B 6E 59 B5 71 E1     Ç.þ³Çƒ...*{nYµqá
E3 9C 0E 73 E7 10 50 00 18 E9 25 F7 AA 7D 9C 30     ãœ.sç.P..é%÷ª}œ0
E6 2F 0F 20 00 3A 64 AA CA 5E 4F CA FF AE 20 04     æ/. .:dªÊ^OÊÿ® .
07 81 40 00 48 00 0A 28 71 21 84 48 06 18 90 0C     ..@.H..(q!„H....
31 14 57 9E 7A CD 63 A0 E0 9B 96 69 C5 18 AE F2     1.WžzÍc à›–iÅ.®ò
E6 07 02 29 01 20 10 70 A1 0F 8C BC 73 F0 78 FA     æ..). .p¡.Œ¼sðxú
9E 1D E1 C2 BF 8C 62 CE CE AC 14 5A A4 E1 45 44     ž.áÂ¿ŒbÎÎ¬.Z¤áED
38 38 85 DB 12 57 3E F6 E0 FB AE 03 04 21 62 8D     88…Û.W>öàû®..!b.
F6 F1 1E 37 1C A2 FF 75 1C F1 02 66 0C 92 07 06     öñ.7.¢ÿu.ñ.f.’..
15 7C 90 15 6F 7D FC BD 13 1E 2B 0C 14 3C 0C 00     .|..o}ü½..+..<..
B0 EA 6F 53 B4 98 D7 80 7A 68 3E 34 69 20 D2 FA     °êoS´˜×€zh>4i Òú
F0 91 FC 75 C6 00 01 18 C0 00 3B 9A C5 E2 7D BF     ð‘üuÆ...À.;šÅâ}¿
```

Some explanation :

- Ignore leading multiple `00` bytes.
- `4C 49 53 54 D6 3C 00 00 6D 6F 76 69` including `30 30 64 63` = AVI "List" header.
- `AD 24 00 00` == decimal `9389` is AVI's own size of H264 item (must read in **Little Endian**).

Notice that the AVI bytes include... 
**-** a note of *item*'s total **size** (`AD 24 00 00`... or reverse for Little Endian : `00 00 24 AD`)
**-** followed by *item* data (`00 00 24 A9 65 88 84 27 ... etc ... C5 E2 7D BF`).

This **size** includes both the 4 bytes of the AVI's"**size**" entry + expected bytes length of the *item*'s own bytes. Can be written simply as:

```
AVI_Item_Size = ( 4 + item_H264_Frame.length );
```

**H.264 video frame bytes in AVI** :

Next follows the *item* data, which is the H.264 **video frame**. By sheer coincidence of formats/bytes layout, it too holds a 4-byte entry for *data*'s **size** (since your H264 is in AVCC format, if it was Annex-B then you would be seeing start code bytes here instead of size bytes).

Unlike AVI bytes, these H264 **size** bytes are written in **Big Endian** format.

- `00 00 24 A9` = size of bytes for this video frame (instead of start code : `00 00 00 01`).
- `65 88 84 27 C7 11 FE B3 C7` = H.264 **keyframe** (always begins X5, where the `X` value is based on other settings).
- Remember after four size bytes (or even start codes) if followed by...

  - byte `X5` = keyframe (IDR), example byte `65`.
  - byte `X1` = P or B frame, example byte `41`.
  - byte `X6` = SEI (Supplemental Enhancement Information).
  - byte `X7` = SPS (Sequence Parameter Set).
  - byte `X8` = PPS (Picture Parameter Set).
  - bytes `00 00 00 X9` = Access unit delimiter.

You can find the H.264 if you search for exact same bytes within AVI file. See [**third**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTMSE.png) picture, these are your H.264 bytes (they are cut & pasted into the AVI container).

Sometimes a frame is sliced into different NAL units. So if you extract a key frame and it only shows 1/2 or 1/3 instead of full image, just grab next one or two NAL and re-try the decode.