# How to play .264 format raw video file from MDVR in C# form application

Tags: c#, video-streaming, decode, video-processing

I'm trying to run a .264 video recorded from MDVR, in a C# application, VLC player is not able to play it, it also has GPS, and data from other sensors embedded in it. I want to decode the stream from file and be able to play the video. Is there any SDK to help me out with this?

ffmpeg fails to play it, vlc fails to play it, MPC-HC fails to play it, AVC can't convert it. and I've never worked on videos before. Thank you.

Comment: If VLC can't play it - it is usually a bad sign. VLC is very good playing back even marginal files. Can you share your file?

Comment: Sample video.


https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aFuA1JhFPpkNlR9xbegqdfueVyhRXpZU

Comment: MDVR Player is able to run it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"FFmpeg fails to play it, VLC fails to play it, MPC-HC fails to play it, AVC can't convert it...*
>
> *"I've never worked on videos before"*

Your actual video data begins at byte position: **4198424**.

See the section "**H.264 video frame bytes in AVI**" of [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46606524/2057709) to know what your video bytes mean. For example... in your file at byte position `4198424`:

Starting bytes `00 00 00 01 67` (is the **SPS**), and `00 00 00 01 68` (is **PPS**), and `00 00 00 01 06` (is **SEI**). All these bytes provide data to setup the decoder (*eg:* notify of the video's frame rate and its width/height etc). Then following bytes `00 00 00 01 65` means "beginning of keyframe data".

**Solution:**
Get to byte position **4198424** and extract everything from those bytes onwards (up to ending of file). This data is in MPEG's **H.264** video format so you could save to disk as `testfile.h264` and then test in a media player (I used the MPC-HC player to display).

[image]